# URL rewrite at Android httpGet + InputStreamReader

Tags: android, url-rewriting, inputstream, http-get

If I have this piece of code and url is **"http://www.example.com/someFile.txt"** everything works just fine. But if I put **"http://www.example.com/export/something"** (with help of URL rewrite/.htaccess on the server) which in desktop browser again outputs the same result in Android I get error **Error w/file: End of input at character 0 of**

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

    String result = "";
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.example.com/export/notWorking");
    HttpResponse response = null;
    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(httpGet, localContext);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            result += line;
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Hot to solve this problem?

**EDIT: Help with user agent**

```
    HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();  
    params.setParameter(CoreProtocolPNames.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.71");
```

**doesn't help.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution - pretty **trivial** I must say - I deleted the emulator, created a new one and then everything is working just fine...so in future - test only on the **device** itself :)